# Using Elfinder extension in Yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I need to use a file manager in pop up which comes on a button click. I am using Yii extension elfinder. I am finding it hard to understand the way of using it. I downloaded the code from bitbucket, put it inside my application in the folder extension. I try to test it using new controller, named it elfcontroller and put the following code (got from the website)

```
class ElfinderController extends CController
{
public function actions()
{
    return array(
        'connector' => array(
            'class' => 'ext.elFinder.ElFinderConnectorAction',
            'settings' => array(
                'root' => Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') . '/uploads/',
                'URL' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/uploads/',
                'rootAlias' => 'Home',
                'mimeDetect' => 'none'
            )
        ),
    );
}
}
```

and i created one more function for rendering the index page(i want the file manager to be in this page)

in the view i wrote the following code

```
$model = new xxxmodel();
$this->widget('ext.elFinder.ElFinderWidget', array(
      'model' => $model,
      'attribute' => 'serverFile',
      'connectorRoute' => 'admin/elfinder/connector',
      )
  );
```

and i included a div for containing it

But i am getting the following error

**Alias "ext.elFinder.ElFinderWidget" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.**

i tried to include alias in config/main.php

I know i am messing some where with the folder structure

here is the path i am using the extension 
**C:\xampp\htdocs\project\protected\extensions\ext.elfinder**

I returned empty after google searches, can any one please explain me how to use this extension to place the code exactly where it is needed to be?

Comment: path should be `C:\xampp\htdocs\project\protected\extensions\elfinder`

Comment: @bool.dev : still not working, it is giving me same error .
I changed the path to same and code inside view is 
`code`$this->widget('elFinder.ElFinderWidget', array(
          'model' => $model,
          'attribute' => 'serverFile',
          'connectorRoute' => 'admin/elfinder/connector',
          )
  );`code`

Comment: Some time ago I tried to use ElFinder extensions too and had some problems. That's why I've written my own. You can try it as an alternative: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ezzeelfinder/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the *extensions* folder already has the `ext` alias, so you don't need to set an alias for it.

Then the extension itself should be placed in the *extensions* folder, somewhat like : *project/extensions/extension-name/* . In your case it should be: *project\extensions\elFinder* , and keep the rest of your code same, i.e continue referring to extension like:

```
ext.elFinder.ElFinderWidget
```

Comment: Thanks Bro, it worked. Can you tell me about the parameters to be passed? 'model','attribute' and 'connectorRout' ??

Comment: Thanks for your prompt replies :)

Comment: `connectorRoute` seems to be the [`url` configuration option](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-configuration-options#wiki-url), `model` and `attribute` are supposed to be the model that stores the file location to search on server (guessing). i'd suggest reading up on elFinder first and getting to know how it works before integrating the extension

Comment: Yup i am doing that. But the Yii extension help is very lean. some where i can see it is called with only one parameter 'connectorRout' . Let me experiment on that. Thanks for your replies

Comment: @bool.dev : Now i am getting a jquery error in the firebug which looks like this 
**TypeError: $("#yw0").elfinder is not a function**
The line of code is
**$('#yw0').elfinder({'url':'/project_folder/index.php/Elfinder/connector','lang':'en_us'});**

it is not prepending http://localhost

Comment: @bool.dev : I had gone for lunch bro, that is why replied late  :-/

Comment: @AkbarAli you don't have to explain yourself (but thanx for letting me know), accepting answers is your sole decision, i was only trying to educate you about how s.o. generally works. anyway, about the error can you see your generated output, is `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/elfinder.min.js"></script>` included?

Comment: These much scripts are loaded at the beginning of the page
`code`
<script type="text/javascript" src="/root_folder/assets/106b3415/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/root_folder/assets/106b3415/jui/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/root_folder/assets/f8078ab4/js/elfinder.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/root_folder/assets/f8078ab4/js/i18n/elfinder.ru.js"></script>

Comment: that looks fine actually, hard to guess cause of error. please ask a new question, as now your problem has *completely changed* from what it was before (which was *path alias/folder structure* problem), asking a new question will get you more views, more people will try to answer, leading to possible solutions. in your new question you could include the code you have tried for integrating the extension. you might also want to check out Ezze's extension instead if you wish, since he is answering here, he might help you directly. i can't offer you anymore help atm, sorry.

Comment: Yup, you are right.
@Ezze : Thanks for your replies bro, Let me try using your extension :)

Comment: @Ezze : I am getting almost similar error on implementing your extension also 

` jQuery(selector).elfinder is not a function` is the error
` jQuery(selector).elfinder(options).elfinder("instance");` is the line throwing error

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem by changing access rights within extension's directory `chmod 000 assets/js/elfinder.min.js` and then changing them back `chmod 644 assets/js/elfinder.min.js`. I don't know what's wrong with it but cleaning `assets` directory of application (in the root directory of the site) is a workaround: `rm -R assets/*`

Comment: The reason of this error is that `elfinder.min.js` included in the head of the page is not a JavaScript file. You can check it in Firebug on the "Net" tab and look for `elfinder.min.js` response.

Comment: @Ezze : I tried cleaning up assets directory under root folder. Gave permission to every one for read and write, still same error happens.

Comment: What are the contents of `elfinder.min.js` file included from root `assets` directory?

Comment: I am not able to understand the question. `elfinder.min.js` is inside root `assets` directory inside a folder with random name. And there are lot of other JS and CSS files created under `assets` folder