# Getting jQuery Error on using ezzeelfinder

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

Hi I am trying to use [ezzeelfinder](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ezzeelfinder/) as file manager

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: jQuery(selector).elfinder is not a function
Query(selector).elfinder().elfinder("instance");
```

I am using the exact code from the Yii extension website. I do not know what is going wrong, I am using windows 7 with Apache (XAMPP)?

Comment: I think i am not able to access the connector action from extension. Is there any way to check this?

Answer (score 2):

Continuing our [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13411800/506695) from previous ElFinder question let me try to explain more.

Can you look at what is inside `elfinder.min.js` file included from `assets` directory (you can use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/): `Net` tab > expand request of `/assets/abcdef/elfinder.min.js` > `Response` tab)? It wasn't a script (but some HTML with error) when I've reproduced a problem with such error. So if this JavaScript file is not included then there is no `elfinder` method extending `jQuery` and the error message you receive is fair.

Seems to me that this one is a permission issue. `elfinder.min.js` file cannot be published to `assets` directory for some reasons. Make sure that all permissions to `elfinder.min.js` file **WITHIN** extension's directory are granted. After granting the permissions to this file clean up `assets` directory and try again. At last, check whether the script has been really published to `assets` directory and has granted permissions there.

I don't know whether it will be helpful for you but I have an archive with demo files that can demonstrate extension's basic usage (made under Ubuntu though): http://ezze.org/yii/ezzeelfinderdemo.zip

Extract the contents of this archive to the root folder of Yii basic application created from command line using `yiic` script.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bro.  It is not permission problem, i guess, `elfinder.min.js` is created under `assets/js` folder. I tried to use elfinder jquery plugin in plain PHP when i removed the connector.php, i came across with the same error. I am new to Yii. i think i messed up with placing the code inside the whole folder structure or in referring the location of connector.

Comment: Thank for the demo project, it is working fine in my local PC, now i will try to integrate it to my project. I have one more doubt. I am using this widget so that user can refer his already uploaded files some where else in an application avoiding re upload of same file. How can i refer that file on double clicking (change the default action of opening on double click)

Comment: I believe that `getFileCallback` client parameter of ElFinder is what you need: https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-configuration-options#wiki-getFileCallback I have just updated my extension to version 0.0.2 and now you can specify any client functions and handlers in `clientOptions` parameter of the widget. Please refer to extension's page on Yii site for details.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, i did not know there was something called accepting answer. But the problem still persists. Your demo is working in my local system, exact code, while integrating with my project fails. I see only one difference, I am rewriting URL using `URLmanager` so that URL will be http://server.com/project/index.php/controller/action/parameter. Can this be a problem?

Comment: I never had problems with this extension rewriting URL. I don't know what your URL rules are and other specific things but you can try to comment your rules and check whether the extension works without them.

Comment: I think i have to try some thing else, can you suggest me a similar tool that will allow the user to upload,delete and refer files from a folder specified to him alone?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't suggest an alternative. I had the similar problem some time ago and as the result wrote my own extension. I still believe that you have some environment issue.

Comment: Has it anything to do with session?